# Delete XML Element from SQL Table

Tags: sql, xml

In the following XML, there are two Elements that I wish to delete. The Elements I wish to delete are tagged as `<Files>` How would I go about doing this?

```
<FooSource xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="FooFileTriggerSource">
  <Files>keepThisFile.txt</Files>
  <Files>deleteThisFile1.txt</Files>
  <Files>deleteThisFile2.bat</Files>
</FooSource>
```

Comment: What RDMS are you using?  In Microsoft SQL, you use XQuery to modify XML, but I'm afraid I can't help with that.

Comment: Is the XML stored in a `varchar()` field, or an `XML` field?  You question asks how to delete the elements, but the example says `deleteThisFile?.???`.  Which are you trying to delete, the element or the file (or both)?